# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'detail.id' in 'field list'")

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I set up a small website, where anyone can store 'name,email,phone' but when I retrieve data from database so I'm getting this error. I don't why?

I'd spend two days to resolve this error but still I'm stuck with it.

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'detail.id' in 'field list'")
>   [SQL: SELECT detail.id AS detail_id, detail.name AS detail_name, detail.email AS detail_email, detail.phone AS detail_phone, detail.date AS detail_date 
>   FROM detail]
>   (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

**My Code `run.py`:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
from db import db
import datetime

# Every website is application in 'flask'
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='template')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:''@localhost/flask' # 'test' is name of your database
# Database access through 'username'= root  and 'password'= None
# My username is 'root' cause I'm on the local host and I'd set any password
# One more thing password is after two dots :
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True



# database access
class detail(db.Model):
    def __init__(self, name, phone, email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.phone = phone

    # table name as is it in your database
    __tablename__='detail'
    # give column names same as in your database otherwise it will give you error
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(13), nullable=False)
    date=db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%d-%m-%Y   %I:%M:%S'))



# routing( setting end points in website) with ['post', 'get'] method
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method=='POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        phone = request.form['phone']

        try:
            # commit to add value in database
            data = detail(name=name, email=email, phone=phone)
            db.session.add(data)
            db.session.commit()

            # after commit redirect to this page
            return redirect(url_for('index'))

        except Exception as e:
            return e

    else:
        # retrieve data from database
        # here is problem
        data =  detail.query.all()  #<<<------------------------------- Error
        return render_template('index.html', data=data)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    # here we are telling to 'flask' that integrate db in 'app'
    db.init_app(app)
    # run flask app and you might be thinking debug mean that if you'll do any change in your application so it'll restart server auto
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**My `db.py` file:**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

'''here we are init. 'username ' and 'password' because if you'll config
this in your 'main.py application' so it'll not be work
so you have to keep it in a another file and import from there
'''
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:''@localhost/flask'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

**My `index.html` file:**

```
<!--
This is just a simple website it will add your 'name' and 'address', 'phone' in database
-->
<html>

<head>
  <title> First flaks app</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Popper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f6cee5f9d4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="text-warning text-center">Flask-app-connect to database</h1>
  <div class='container table-responsive w-50 mt-5'>
    <table class="table table-dark table-hover">
      <thead class='bg-info text-dark'>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      {% for data in data %}
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{{data.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{data.Email}}</td>
            <td>{{data.Phone}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="container text-center mt-5">
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add to
      database</button>

    <!-- Box Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h2>Add to database</h2>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <!-- Form -->
            <form action="/" method="POST" role="form" class="was-validated">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name" required>
                <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
                <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="phone" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" required>
                <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-spinner">Commit</button>
            </form>
            <!-- Form end -->
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!--End box modal-->

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**I expect that:**

How can I get all data from database and put it in `index.html` through loop.

Please, make me understand, where I'm doing mistake?

Comment: The error "Unknown column 'detail.id' in 'field list'" suggests, that your model does not match the table in the database.

Comment: How to fix this?

Comment: I'm new in `flask-sqlalchemy`. Could you tell me where I gone wrong?

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: when I remove this line `data = detail.query.all()` in my `run.py` It's works otherwise not.

Comment: You likely changed your model after you created the tables. Have a look at flask-migrate to keep model and DB in sync. Note, however, that stackoverflow is a question-answer site and not a step by step guide to <topic>. Please put some effort into learning the concepts that you want to use by reading documentation, following tutorials, etc.

Comment: I'm seeking you understanding, not step by step guide.

Comment: Where I can learn this thing `flask-migrate model`?

Comment: But In those videos they are showing me only `insert data` instead of `GET` data from database.

Comment: I think migration is use for handle database through command line.

Comment: Hey dude, can you please fix this. It'll better understanding for me.

Answer (score 2):

### Understanding the error

The reason you are seeing this error is because as @moi mentioned your model and database don't match.

Your model has five attributes `id`, `name`, `email`, `phone`, and `date`. However, your database does not have a column called `id` in the `detail` table.

This causes an error when you query the database because SQLAlchemy specifies each column it is querying in the `SELECT` statement. In other words it says it wants the data from columns `id`, `name`, `email`, `phone`, and `date`. Unfortunatly, the database does not have a column called `id`, so it returns an error.

This was likely caused by you creating the model with out `id` and then adding it afterward. Thus you updated your model and not the database.

### How to fix this

You need to get your database in sync with your model. You will need to run the following commands from your terminal.

**First, install flask-migrate.**

```
$ pip install Flask-Migrate
```

**Second, configure flask-migrate**

Read the Example section in the docs at a minimum for this. [Flask Migrate Docs](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#example)

**Third, setup the migration folder.**

```
$ flask db init
```

If this produces a `Could not locate a Flask application.` error. You will need to set the `FLASK_APP` environment variable. Replace `run.py` with the filename of your Flask app.

MacOS/Linux

```
$ export FLASK_APP=run.py
```

Windows

```
$ set FLASK_APP=run.py
```

**Fourth, create your first migration.**

```
$ flask db migrate
```

Once this is done you should find a new file `xxxxxxxxxxxx_.py` in your `/migrations/versions` directory. This is an Alembic migration file.

At this point you have three options.

*Option 1*: you can drop your `details` table, and let `flask-migrate` create a fresh one. **You will loose any data in it.** Then run the `upgrade` command.

*Option 2*: you can hand edit the new Alembic migration file. You will need to change the `upgrade()` function so it does not try to create a new `details` table since it already exists, but instead adds the `id` column.

*Option 3*: you can delete the `sa.Column("id" sa.Integer()...` line from the `upgrade()` function as well as any other columns not in your database. Then manually create a table in your database called `alembic_version` with a single primary key `VARCHAR` column called `version_num` with a length 32. Then create a single entry in the `alembic_version` table with the value of the `Revision ID` from the alembic migration created above. Then run `$ flask db migrate` again. This will create a second alembic version file that should be able to upgrade your database.

Based on the state of your application and your level of experiance I would recommend option 1.

**Fifth, upgrade your database.**

```
$ flask db upgrade
```

### Read the documentation

I highly recomend reading the documentation on both flask-migrate and Alembic. Flask-migrate is a well built wrapper for Alembic for flask appications.

[Flask Migrate Docs](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#example)

[Alembic Docs](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Did you use option 1, 2 or 3?

Comment: yes, when I run command `flask db migrate`. I'm getting same error.

Comment: You may need to comment out the `data =  detail.query.all()` to run it the migration the first time.

Answer (score -1):

While inserting a varchar value, if you will forget to add single quotes, then this error will arise. Following is the error − mysql> insert into DemoTable798 values (100,Adam); ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Adam' in 'field list'